# spark -- filter down element in a list of list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

new to pyspark --
I have a bunch of text documents and I would like to get all the individual words from these text documents.

I can see this step turns each document into a list of words alright:
`words = documents.map(lambda v: re.split('[\W_\']+',v.lower()))
display(words.toDF())`

But I also want to remove stopwords (a list of words defined somewhere before this code) from this. The issue is that the RDD "words" doesn't appear to be simply a list of words. It is a list of lists of words. 
For example, words.first() would return a list of words, not just one word. So how do I remove any word that belongs to stopwords from "words"?

I tried `words2 = words.map(lambda x:x if x not in stoplist)` and got errors "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example as follows:

```
pattern = re.compile('[\W_\']+')

(documents
    .flatMap(lambda v: pattern.split(v.lower()))
    .filter(lambda w: w and w not in stoplist))
```

or if you want to keep records without flattening:

```
(documents
    .map(lambda v: pattern.split(v.lower()))
    .map(lambda ws: [w for w in ws if w and w not in stoplist]))
```